# Read xml attribute error with QXmlStreamReader in QT

Tags: xml, qt, qt5

I meet a very strange problem. I cannot read an attribute of a xml node correctly with `QXmlStreamReader` in one case - reading a ip string node.

Following is my xml file *test.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <ip type="UiParamElem">192.168.1.100</ip>   
</Document>
```

I want to read the `ip` node value and its attribute, following codes can reproduce that problem:

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QFile>
#include <QXmlStreamReader>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  QFile xml("test.xml");
  QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(&xml);
  if(!xml.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
      return -1;

  // get project root
  while(!xmlReader.atEnd())
  {
    if (xmlReader.isStartElement())
    {
      std::cout << "start element name " << xmlReader.name().toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
      if (xmlReader.name() == "ip")
      {
        QString ip = xmlReader.name().toString();
        auto typevalue = xmlReader.attributes().value("type");
        QString ipValue = xmlReader.readElementText();
        std::cout << "ip value " << ipValue.toStdString()
                  << " typevalue " << typevalue.toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
        xmlReader.readNext();
      }
    }
    else
    {
        xmlReader.readNext();
    }
  }

  return a.exec();
}
```

And the unexpected output is as following, which is not expected - the attribute is wrong:

```sh
start element name Document
start element name ip
ip value 192.168.1.100 typevalue 100ramElem
```

What is that `100ramElem` part? But `UiParamElem` is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert QStringRef to QString as returned by value("type"). According to Qt docs QStringRef provides a read-only subset of the QString API. Calling toString() returns a copy of the data as a real QString instance.

```
auto typevalue = xmlReader.attributes().value("type").toString();
```

Comment: I doubt it. Because from my output log - produced by `std::cout` line, `typevalue` has been converted into string, and the result is still wrong.